# using a Brush stored in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am a WPF newbie and I want to create a program wide Brush that I can reference again and again. I have a brush in a ResourceDicitonary with full definition.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options">
   <DrawingBrush x:Key="rg1024_metal_effect" Stretch="Uniform">
```

I have added this to app.xaml.

```
 <Color x:Key="SteelBrush">#FFFFFF</Color>
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="{StaticResource rg1024_metal_effect}"/>
```

But I get the error:

> "rg1024_metal_effect could not be resolved"

I know this should be easy but for a freshie like me - that's not so easy.

Comment: How are you merging in your ResourceDictionary?

Comment: `rg1024_metal_effect` is not a `Color`. It's a `DrawingBrush`. You can't set the `Color` property of a `SolidColorBrush` to a `DrawingBrush`. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a resource in a `ResourceDictionary` named for example "Dictionary1.xaml" and you want to reference this resource from another resource that you define in another `ResourceDictionary`, such as for example `App.xaml`, you should merge `Dictionary1.xaml` into `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="{StaticResource SteelBrush}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Dictionary1.xaml:**

```
<Color x:Key="SteelBrush">#FFFFFF</Color>
```

In your example, `rg1024_metal_effect` is not a `Color` but a `DrawingBrush` though. You can't set the `Color` property of a `SolidColorBrush` to a `DrawingBrush`.

Comment: How would you approach this then? I'd like to make this available to the entire application and do not know how to reference it.

Comment: @Matthew: How do you approach what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `Color` in `AppBrush`, you'll need to define it like `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="{StaticResource SteelBrush}"/>`

If you would like to add this brush to button, you can use the same way, like `<Button Background="{StaticResource SteelBrush}"/>` or create s `Style` for `Button` in your resource dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" x:Key="StyleKey">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SteelBrush}"/>
…
</Style>
```

Comment: that worked... but you would I reference this brush when say adding a fill to a button?

Comment: @Matthew I'll add it yo the answer